# Reading specific data row from CSV file using Coded UI

Tags: c#, csv, coded-ui-tests

Here's an example of  the problem am looking to solve:

I have a CSV file with 2 columns (username, password) and 10 rows (different username and password).

My goal is to have my first test method use the first username/ password combination, the 2nd test method uses the 2nd row and so on. Right now, if I run my tests, the first test method uses all 10 rows of data.

Is there a way for me to restrict my test method to read only a specific row(say row 1) in my csv file? Am using `TestContext.DataRow["UserName"].ToString()` now. But I think the way the test cases run in coded UI, it automatically runs 10 times.

Comment: How about posting your test method?

Comment: You should probably put the code, without it it's not possible to see how to change it so it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, I think i figured it out. It's just a basic login page. I used this syntax to get my code to refer to the specific column in the CSV, TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows[rownumber].ItemArray[column 
 number].ToString();